# core data predicate format in string swift4

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate

I am using core data. For fetching data I want to give predicate as string. I have stored predicate in string attribute in database. 
Below is code I am trying

```
 let request = NSFetchRequest<Tasks>(entityName: "Tasks")
            print("Query is .." ,item.query!)
            request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: item.myqueryString!)
```

myqueryString is string attribute in core data where I am storing predicate as - 
projectName == "spot"

But on fetching data it is giving error "NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath spot not found in entity".
Anyone can explain what is wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read [Predicate Format String Syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html)

Comment: str = "projectName == 'spot'                                                            "request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: str)  is working but            request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: item.myqueryString!)  is not working though both are strings?? myqueryString is string attribute in core data.

Comment: The format must be `<attribute> <operator> <value>` like `projectName == 'spot'`

Comment: yes my item.myqueryString is projectName == 'spot' but still its not working.